# jquery option text return empty

Tags: jquery, html-select

In jquery from version 1.7 to latest

```
$('option:selected[text~="some text"]')
```

returning empty array.

In previous versions its working good.

Why? Bug?

Update: html:

```
<select class='txt :required' name='terms' size="30" style="width:277px"
    onchange="reset_cost()" id="terms">
  <option label="авто/мото" value="1">авто/мото</option>
  <option label="бизнес/финансы" value="16">бизнес/финансы</option>
  ....
</select>
```

Comment: We need to see your HTML before we can make that determination

Comment: text isn't an attribute... does that selector work in a stylesheet? I would consider that selector working in 1.7 being a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the html you posted you need to change `text` to `label`.

```
$('option:selected[label~="some text"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` syntax is for selecting attributes.  `text` is not an attribute.  To select based on the text of an element use `:contains`.

```
$('option:selected:contains("some text")')
```

Since you're using `~=`, which looks between word boundaries, you might want to change the selector (note the space before `some text`)

```
$('option:selected:contains(" some text")')
```